# How to renew only one domain with certbot?

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I have multiple domains with multiple certificates:

```
$ ll /etc/letsencrypt/live/
> domain1.com
> domain2.com
> domain3.com
> ...
```

I need to renew only `domain1.com`, but the command `certbot renew` renews certificates for all domains. How can I renew certain certificate explicitly?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use this command (for Apache server):

```
certbot --apache certonly -n -d domain1.com
```

- `--apache` for apache server, use `--nginx` flag for nginx server
- `-n` option execute the command without prompt
- `-d domain1.com` to execute only for domain1.com

You can test with `--dry-run`, and you can use `--pre-hook` and `--post-hook` like  with `certbot renew`

Source : https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates

Comment: your answer helped me with nginx as well. please add nginx server too --nginx

Answer (score 178):

Renew a single certificate using `renew` with the `--cert-name` option.

(`certonly` *creates* a certificate for one or more domains, replacing it if exists).

### Example

```
certbot renew --cert-name domain1.com --dry-run
```

Remove `--dry-run` to actually renew.

---

### Cert-name != Domain name

Note that the value supplied to --cert-name option **is a certificate name** (not a domain name) found using

```
certbot certificates
```

Returning a list like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: myfundomains.com
    Domains: myfundomains.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-05-04 04:28:05+00:00 (VALID: 67 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfundomains.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfundomains.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: ask.myfundomain.com
    Domains: ask.myfundomain.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-03-13 18:59:40+00:00 (VALID: 16 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/ask.myfundomain.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/ask.myfundomain.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: forums.myfundomain.com
    Domains: forums.myfundomain.com forum.myfundomain.com
    Expiry Date: 2018-04-11 16:39:18+00:00 (VALID: 45 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/forums.myfundomain.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/forums.myfundomain.com/privkey.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice how the third Certificate name (forums.myfundomain.com) contains **multiple domains**:

- forums.myfundomains.com
- forum.myfundomains.com

### Restart Apache / nginx

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
new certificate deployed without reload, fullchain is
/etc/letsencrypt/live/ask.myfundomain.com/fullchain.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Remember to restart your webserver to make use of the new certificate.

Comment: Yeah, this method is very useful when you are using custom build of nginx.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on (example) www.domain.nl and domain.nl as follows (just one command): certbot renew -n --cert-name www.domain.nl --force-renewal

Comment: `service nginx reload` will do the trick - no need to restart

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command on Nginx server

1. Stop Nginx server

   sudo systemctl stop nginx
2. Renew certbot

   sudo certbot certonly --force-renew -d domain1.com
3. Start Nginx server

   sudo systemctl start nginx
4. Check current certs

   sudo certbot certificates

Results:

> Found the following certs: Certificate Name: domain1.com Serial
> Number: 4564f55f3fe993964f8bbc65249a7ed4c91 Key Type: RSA Domains:
> domain1.com Expiry Date: 2022-12-19 01:34:25+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
> Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem
> Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem

Answer (score 0):

To add a new domain name
Wrote *-le-ssl* file manually and run the below command

```
 sudo certbot -d domainname --expand
```

Since automatic ssl file creation in Ubuntu 22 didn't support me